# How can I figure out why Xorg is SIGALRM and using 90%+ CPU?

Tags: xorg, cpu-usage

`htop` tells me that XORG is using 90% of my CPU

```
10099 root       20   0  558M 70848 59856 R 92.2  1.6  1h41:09 /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.Hnbv14PGS0
```

(92% in that case)

When I run strace on the PID, it seems pretty obvious that this is where most of the problem is happening:

```
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 64990921152193766
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 59621924268134867
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 3278708391
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 72057589759737855
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 3278965186
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 3279090189
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
```

Every 10-20 lines I see roughly the same lines (the `rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 72057589759737855` line seems to be popular)

How can I figure out why this is happening? If I exit X those lines go away... and apparently, as I just discovered, if I jump back to another virtual terminal, that's *all* that comes out of strace.